# how to make $http.get Url dynamic in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Can we make dynamic url like whenever we select a value from first drop down the url should be http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=value.

It means when we select value(USD) in first drop down the same value apply at the end of the url(http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD) and the json data will come from that url.

Comment: What do you mean dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ngModel (fromType) on the first select will hold the selected value. So get the data from the $scope.fromType and add that to the url like this

```
$http.get('http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=' + $scope.fromType.label).then(function(res) {
    $scope.fromValue = 1;
    $scope.ConvertCurrency();
    var i = 0;
    angular.forEach(res.data.rates, function(value, key) {
        if (key == "USD" || key == "EUR" || key == "CAD") {
            $scope .rates.push({ value: value, label: key });
        }
        i++;
    });
});
```

**Update**

Ok, so basically I made some assumptions here.

1. At start, we should load all rates in the first select ($scope.getAllRates())
2. When a rate is selected in the first select, we should load rates connected to that currency in the other select ($scope.getRate())

If this is the case your view would be like this

```
<div ng-app="CurrencyConv" ng-controller="ConvertCtrl">
    <input type="number" placeholder="0.00" ng-model="fromValue" ng-change="ConvertCurrency();" min='0'>
    <select ng-model="fromType" required ng-change="ConvertCurrency(); getRate();" ng-options="f as f.label for f in rates"></select> 

    <input type="text" placeholder="0.00" ng-model="toValue" ng-change="ConvertCurrency()">
    <select ng-model="toType" required ng-change="ConvertCurrency()" ng-options="f as f.label for f in toRates"></select>
</div>
```

And the controller

```
App.controller('ConvertCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.rates = [];
    $scope.toRates = [];

    $scope.toType = {};
    $scope.fromType = {};
    $scope.fromValue = 1;

    $scope.getAllRates = function(){
        $http.get('https://api.fixer.io/latest').then(function(res) {
                angular.forEach(res.data.rates, function(value, key) {
                    if (key == "USD" || key == "EUR" || key == "CAD") {
                        $scope.rates.push({ value: value, label: key });
                    }
                });
            });
    };

    $scope.getRate = function(){
       $scope.toRates = [];
       if(typeof $scope.fromType.label !== undefined){
        $http.get('https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=' + $scope.fromType.label).then(function(res) {
                $scope.fromValue = 1;
                $scope.toValue = 0;
                angular.forEach(res.data.rates, function(value, key) {
                    if (key == "USD" || key == "EUR" || key == "CAD") {
                        $scope.toRates.push({ value: value, label: key });
                    }
                });
                $scope.toType = $scope.toRates[0];
                $scope.ConvertCurrency();
            });
       }
    };

    $scope.ConvertCurrency = function() {
        if($scope.toRates.length > 0){
          $scope.toValue = $scope.fromValue * ($scope.toType.value * (1 / $scope.fromType.value));
        }
    };

    //init
    $scope.getAllRates();
}]);
```

[Here's](https://plnkr.co/edit/O5ApbTTSGaVm1iIuCJfT?p=preview) a plunker

Comment: @VishalJoshi You need to call the Get after the first select is changed.

Comment: @VishalJoshi added a plunker

Comment: @VishalJoshi Didn't this example solve your programming problem? If you have problem with what data that should be the base data, then just change the api call.

Comment: I have read that text 5 times and still can't see what my answer is missing to solve that question.

Comment: @VishalJoshi Ok, np :) I thought I had it completly wrong there for a second.. Good that you solved the last part. Please upvote or/and accept answer

Comment: @VishalJoshi ok, That can be done. But, you need to accept/upvote my answer now. Also, I saw that you have not accepted any answers of any question you have raised. If you want people to help you, you should man up and give them the credit for the time they spent in helping you. If you don't accept answers whats the point of helping you

Comment: @VishalJoshi ok, I see. So do you want the value, which is selected in the first select, to be added to the second select?

Comment: Yes first dropdown = CAD, EUR, USD and Second dropdown = CAD, EUR, USD

Comment: @VishalJoshi I updated the plunker and fixed the logic calculation of the currency convertion. Read comments in the plunker to see the logic

Answer (score 0):

Set ng-model to your select and store that value in $scope. When making request, set that value as a parameter.

```
    $http.get('http://api.fixer.io/latest', { params:{base: $scope.fromType.label}}).then(function(res) {
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just append your ngModel to your request url

```
$scope.makeRequest = function(offset){

   $http.get('http://api.fixer.io/latest?base='+$scope.fromType.label).then(function(res) {
    $scope.fromValue = 1;
    $scope.ConvertCurrency();
    var i = 0;
    angular.forEach(res.data.rates, function(value, key) {
        if (key == "USD" || key == "EUR" || key == "CAD") {
            $scope .rates.push({ value: value, label: key });
        }
        i++;
    });
   });
 }

  $scope.ConvertCurrency = function() {


    $scope.toValue = $scope.fromValue * ($scope.toType.value * (1 / $scope.fromType.value));
 $scope.makeRequest();
};
```

If you need to make different request every time, you need to set your request in a function and call it.

Comment: GET parameter is not appended correctly. There is "=" missing in the url.